# Color Binding Not Working for Data Templates in Win8 App

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-8, colors, windows-runtime

I'm currently trying to add some sort of a Color Theme feature to a Win8 App I'm working at... I've though of making a binding from a vm, and everything works fine for static UI elements. But, I'm adding some notes (my model) into a DB, and they also appear on the screen into a GridView.

But in the declared DataTemplate for the GridView ItemTemplate, the Color Binding will not work at all...

My template looks like this :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Height="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0"  Background="Lavender"  Opacity="50"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Content}" Foreground="DodgerBlue" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Border Grid.Row="1"  Background="DodgerBlue" Opacity="70"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Subject}" Foreground="LightBlue" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="DodgerBlue" Opacity="70"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Importance}" Foreground="Black"  FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}" />
</Grid>
```

What I tried was simply instead of `Foreground="DodgerBlue"` to `Foreground="{Binding ColorTheme}"` but it had no effect, the `SolidColorBrush` was not acquired from vm....

Is there any workaround for this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the ColorTheme property?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the Output window while debugging?

Comment: ColorTheme is of type SolidColorBrush.No errors found, just binding doesn't seem to work, shows me white colored text...

Answer (score 0):

Color binding (or better: brush binding) should work just fine - in `GridView.ItemTemplate` scenario and elsewhere.

You haven't given enough info to pinpoint why it doesn't work in your case, but here is a small sample I've just tried out:

`GridView` to put in your page:

```
<GridView Width="600" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}"
          x:Name="GridViewName">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Width="50" Height="50" 
                       Foreground="{Binding Color}" Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

View model class bound as `DataContext` for your page:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        GridItems = new List<GridItem>
            {
                new GridItem {Text = "First", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)},
                new GridItem {Text = "Second", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow)},
                new GridItem {Text = "Third", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)},
                new GridItem {Text = "Fourth", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)},
            };
    }
}
```

`GridItem` class:

```
public class GridItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Brush Color { get; set; }
}
```

The result:

[image: Color bound grid view]

EDIT:

I need to point out that inside data template `DataContext` is set to the current item of the bound collection (`GridItems` in my case) not to the page `DataContext` (`ViewModel` in my case).

This means that by setting `{Binding Color}` to a control property you're binding to `GridItem.Color` not to `ViewModel.Color`. To make the latter work you first need to access the parent `DataContext` using the `ElementName` syntax as you already suggested in your own answer: `{Binding DataContext.ColorTheme, ElementName=GridViewName}` - this binds to a named element on the page and allows you to access its properties, `DataContext` being `ViewModel` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Altough I didn't really find out the actual explanation on why the below works (and I hope someone more experience, maybe could explain me), this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868992/access-property-of-datacontext-inside-itemtemplate), seemed to have worked for me.

Not very sure, but was a matter of DataContext, so instead of trying a binding like this : `Foreground={Binding ColorTheme}`, I changed to this : `Foreground={Binding DataContext.ColorTheme, ElementName=MyGridViewName}"`.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the info you provided here. It didn't work for you because your `ColorTheme` property is not on individual items like other bound properties (e.g. `Importance` or `Subject`) but at the level of the collection.